# Google Map wrong marker clicked event when two markers are adjacent

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have applied custom PNG images (about the same size as the default marker clusterer circle) for markers and this strange thing happened. When two markers are close (but even when they are not overlapping), I need to tap a marker twice, because the first tap wrongly gives me the previous marker.

That is,

- There are two markers A and B close to each other.
- I tap A, and then I get a marker clicked event with A.
- Then, I tap B, but I get a marker clicked event with A.
- If I tab B again, then I get a marker clicked event with B.

To reproduce this problem I created a separate project and did not change the marker image. I placed two markers ("My house" and "Garage") close to each other, and run the app in an emulator, and use a mouse to click accurate places. I placed the mouse on the centre (black dot) of the "Garage" marker and kept clicking it *without* moving the mouse. Below is the log.

```
[ 12-31 13:42:24.509 28921:28921 D/         ]
Garage is clicked

[ 12-31 13:42:25.664 28921:28921 D/         ]
My house is clicked

[ 12-31 13:42:26.819 28921:28921 D/         ]
Garage is clicked

[ 12-31 13:42:28.066 28921:28921 D/         ]
My house is clicked

[ 12-31 13:42:29.333 28921:28921 D/         ]
Garage is clicked

[ 12-31 13:42:30.503 28921:28921 D/         ]
My house is clicked
```

As you see, even though I clicked on the exact same place the marker event's argument kept changing. Is this a bug?

[image]

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mapFragment = this.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapView) as SupportMapFragment;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    var mMap:GoogleMap? = null;

    override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap?)
    {
        mMap = p0;

        var marker = MarkerOptions()
        marker.position(LatLng(51.501518, -0.141847));
        marker.title("My house");
        p0?.addMarker(marker);

        var marker2 = MarkerOptions()
        marker2.position(LatLng(51.501518, -0.142300));
        marker2.title("Garage");
        p0?.addMarker(marker2);

        p0?.setOnMarkerClickListener {
            marker ->
            Log.d("", marker.title + " is clicked")
            true;
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    map:cameraTargetLat="51.501518"
    map:cameraTargetLng="-0.141847"
    map:cameraZoom="16"/>
```

PS: It does not seem to have to be that adjacent. I tried these values, and it still happened.

```
    marker.position(LatLng(51.501518, -0.141847));
    marker2.position(LatLng(51.501518, -0.142500));
```

[image]

Then, I further separated the two until,

```
    marker.position(LatLng(51.501518, -0.141847));
    marker2.position(LatLng(51.501518, -0.142800));
```

[image]

Now, clicking the centre (black dot) did not reproduce the problem. But clicking on on the off-centre of the maker which is close to the other marker still reproduced the problem.

Comment: I propose that the underlying clickable boxes for the nearly overlapping markers are actually overlapping.  This would explain why both markers are reachable from the same spot.  As to the toggling, we might have to look the maps source code to explain that.

Comment: If that is the case, and I should not handle clicked event when markers are adjacent, how do I know if the markers adjacent in the clicked event? I know returning false would let Google Maps do zooming-in, but I must know  whether the markers are adjacent first before returning false. In fact, a few days ago [I had asked that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993518/google-maps-handle-marker-click-event-only-when-markers-are-separated-enough) but there was no answer. I thought this would be a common requirements.

Comment: The immediate workaround is to just zoom in further.  Not nice, but it should avoid this.  With regard to your other question, everyone is on vacation right now.  Consider adding a sizeable bounty to that other question, or this one.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I was not on a vacation, but the damn cheap Internet was out of service so I could not connect to the Internet. If there is no easy, in-built way to do that, I think I would have to create some kind of lists (lat,lng) for markers and calculate distances to check if there are no adjacent markers.

Comment: I believe this issue was already reported in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62556358

Comment: Yes, it is. I wish Google would implement a solution for this in newer versions.

Answer (score -1):

Can reproduce 100% here. I have found a workaround, just setting an inverted zIndex to the MarkerOptions.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
        Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .zIndex(locations.size() - 1 - i) // this avoids the bug when the bottom marker is selected
        );
    }
```