# Google Maps get marker(s) by specifying an area on the visible map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to get adjacent markers of the clicked markers to workaround [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040110/google-map-wrong-marker-clicked-event-when-two-markers-are-adjacent).

I wonder if there is a method in Google Maps or in Google Maps Utils to get markers in a specified portion of the visible portion of the Google Maps instance. If there is no such thing, I could iterate all markers one by one and calculate the distances from the clicked marker on the screen (not geological distance), but that seems to be inefficient.

Comment: Have you try to use map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion() From VisibleRegion you can get LatLongBounds.